# Salesforce DX, DreamHouse app

Tags: salesforcedx

Unable to install `Dreamhouse app` in my DevHub from create unmanaged package `v 1.0` in Trailhead Unlocked Packages for customers/build your first unlocked package.

After using following command:

```
sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package dreamhouse@1.0.0-1 -k test1234 -r -u nks
```

I got error as:

> Waiting for the package install request to complete. Status = IN_PROGRESS
>   ERROR:  Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors:
>
> 1. Apex compile failure, Details: line 15, column 20: Variable does not exist: cmsft_guestPassesService
> 2. Apex compile failure, Details: line 52, column 30: Variable does not exist: cmsft_guestPassesService
> 3. Apex compile failure, Details: line 27, column 55: Invalid type: fflib_SObjectDomain
> 4. Apex compile failure, Details: line 39, column 23: @Override specified for non-overriding method: void Chargeable.onBeforeInsert()

Please let me know how I can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an installation of an unlocked package, all the existing unit tests are launched at the time. Try to run your tests before installation to make sure if it's problem in your org. If it's not, please provide me with a response

Comment: thanks so much for help now installed successfully.